# Get Vue to update view/component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, self-updating

I'm stuck at a crossroads with a component I am working on.

I have the following component "RecentUpdates"

Within it I am passing props down to a few other components, as you can see from the top of the file.

My problem is when adding a new post, I can not figure out how to get the correct update object array back and i also can not figure out the correct 'Vue way' to update the data prop that is being passed down to the "PostList" component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <PostFilter v-on:selectedCategory="getSelectedPosts" v-on:showAllPosts="showAllPosts" :user="user" :categories="categories"/>

    <PostList v-if="recent_posts[0]" :categories="categories" :posts="recent_posts[0]" :user="user"/>

    <Pagination v-on:getPreviousPage="getPreviousPage" v-on:getNextPage="getNextPage"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import PostList from './PostList';
import PostFilter from './PostFilter';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import EventBus from '../event-bus';


export default {

  name: 'RecentUpdates',

  data: () => ({
    errors: [],
    recent_posts: [],
  }),

  props: ['categories', 'user'],

  components: {
    PostList,
    PostFilter,
    Pagination
  },

  created() {

    if (this.user.meta.selected_categories[0] == 0) {
      this.showAllPosts();
    }

    // do not call here, not working as expected
    // is switching selected category to an incorrect one
    // this.updateList();

    this.getSelectedCategory();
  },

  watch: {
    recent_posts: function(newValue) {

      EventBus.$on('addPost', function(newPost) {
        console.log(newPost);

        this.$forceUpdate();


        //this.recent_posts.push(newPost);

        //this.$set(this.recent_posts, newPost, newPost);

        // this.$nextTick(function () {
        //   this.recent_posts.push(newPost);
        // });


      });

        console.log(this.recent_posts[0]);


      // this.$nextTick(function () {
      //   console.log(this.recent_posts[0]) // => 'updated'
      // });

      // if (this.user.meta.selected_categories[0] == 0) {
      //   EventBus.$on('addPost', this.showAllPosts);
      // } else {
      //   EventBus.$on('addPost', this.getSelectedCategory);
      // }
      //this.updateList();
    }
  },

  methods: {

    // updateList() {

    //   if (this.user.meta.selected_categories[0] == 0) {
    //     EventBus.$on('addPost', this.showAllPosts);
    //     //EventBus.$emit('newPost');

    //   } else {
    //     EventBus.$on('addPost', this.getSelectedCategory);
    //     //EventBus.$emit('newPost');
    //   }

    // },

    getSelectedCategory() {

      let categoryId = this.user.meta.selected_categories[0];

      this.getSelectedPosts(categoryId);
    },

    showAllPosts() {

      axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&status=[publish,resolved,unresolved]', 
        {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
      .then(response => {
        this.recent_posts = [];
        //this.recent_posts = response.data;
        //console.log(response.data);
        this.recent_posts.push(response.data);
        console.log(this.recent_posts[0]);

      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
    },

    getSelectedPosts(categoryId) {

      axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&status=[publish,resolved,unresolved]&categories=' + categoryId,
        {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
      .then(response => {
        this.recent_posts = [];
        //console.log(response.data);

        this.recent_posts.push(response.data);

        console.log(this.recent_posts[0]);


      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
    },

    /**
     * Pagination methods
     *
     */
    getPreviousPage(page) {
      axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&status=[publish,resolved,unresolved]&page=' + page, 
        {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
      .then(response => {
        this.recent_posts = response.data;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
    },

    getNextPage(page) {
      axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&status=[publish,resolved,unresolved]&page=' + page, 
        {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
      .then(response => {
        this.recent_posts = response.data;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
    }
  },
}

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: If you feel like your vue state - data -  is going bigger i really recommend you to check [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) what it basically does is managing you data as centralized store so you only have one big place to store your data in.

Comment: The project itself is not that big that I would need to incorporate VueX. I had already thought of that but my problem is only with this one component. That is why I make use of a custom EventBus.

Comment: What does PostList do? It's called a list, but you seem to be passing it just the first element of an array.

Comment: Just loops through the object array of posts using a v-for and passes each individual post as a prop to the Post comp

Comment: `recent_posts[0]` is an array of post objects? Inside PostList, adding a new post should be as simple as using `this.posts.push(newPost)`.

Comment: I will try that when I get back from my lunch break. I was not sure if RecentUpdates comp or PostList would be the correct comp to attempt to add the new post in.

Comment: @Bert would I put this into a method or a lifecycle hook? a watch or updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a number of issues I see reading through your code.

1. You have a `recent_posts` data property, which is an array. When you make your ajax call to get the posts you push the response which is *also* an array into the `recent_posts` array. Why? Why not just set `recent_posts = response.data`? Then you won't have to be passing `recent_posts[0]` around.
2. You're setting up your `EventBus` handler inside a watcher. This is really unusual. Typically you would set up a handler inside `created` or `mounted`.
3. `this` inside the EventBus handler likely refers to the EventBus and not your Vue. Ideally, you would set the handler to be a method on the component, which is already bound to the Vue. Something like `EventBus.$on("addPost", this.addPost)`.
4. Once you've done all that, adding a new post should be as simple as `this.recent_posts.push(newPost)`.

Here is what I might recommend.

```
export default {
  name: 'RecentUpdates',
  data(){
    return {
      errors: [],
      recent_posts: []
    }
  },
  props: ['categories', 'user'],
  components: {
    PostList,
    PostFilter,
    Pagination
  },
  created() {
    if (this.user.meta.selected_categories[0] == 0) {
      this.showAllPosts();
    }
    this.getSelectedCategory();

    EventBus.$on("addPost", this.addPost)
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
    EventBus.$off("addPost", this.addPost)
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts(url){
      axios.get(url, {headers: {'X-WP-Nonce': portal.nonce}})
        .then(response => this.recent_posts = response.data)
        .catch(e => this.errors.push(e))
    },
    showAllPosts() {
      const url = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&status=[publish,resolved,unresolved]';
      this.getPosts(url);
    },
    getSelectedPosts(categoryId) {
      const url = '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&status=[publish,resolved,unresolved]&categories=' + categoryId;
      this.getPosts(url);     
    },     
    addPost(newPost){
      this.recent_posts.push(newPost)
    },
    ... //other methods
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you greatly! I had the recent_posts = response.data but got confused from the Vue docs saying to use the other. I preferred what you stated, much cleaner. Thank you for the clarification. So to add a new post to the list would I still add it in RecentUpdates or in PostList?

Comment: @ZachTackett You are already set up with a bus, so for now I would get the bus working. My comments were made before I understood you were using a bus. So, I would do it at the moment in RecentUpdates.

Comment: Ok, so the example you have provided is working. But i am facing another caveat. I'm using the WordPress REST API in order to retrieve the user/post/category data in order to get the posts I use the following axios GET request 

axios.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&status=[publish,resolved,unresolved]

My problem now is that I need to retrieve the _embed=true back from the POST response but not sure how to get that back from the API.

It's always something...
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ZachTackett unfortunately I really know anything about the WordPress API and would have to resort to the documentation. Perhaps if you can't find the answer in the docs, another question in the [tag:wordpress] tag would be appropriate.

Comment: Thats cool man. Just some more digging around and researching I have to do. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Well I was able to fix my error, however, the dom is still not re-rendering upon the addition of a new post. Any more ideas?

Comment: Ok my mistake. This is working perfectly! You're the man. The posts were getting added to the bottom of the Post List and not the top. Gotta figure out how to fix that

Comment: @ZachTackett use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to push items at the beginning of an array. Or sort the array.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I had just started looking at those and was typing in unshift as the message popped up in my RSS feeder. You're the man!

Answer (score 1):

Try using kebab-case in your event listeners instead of camelCase:

1. Example: v-on:selectedCategory="getSelectedPosts" should be v-on:selected-category="getSelectedPosts".
2. Example: v-on:showAllPosts="showAllPosts" should be v-on:show-all-posts="showAllPosts" or even using the shortcut @show-all-posts="showAllPosts".

UPDATE: If you can provide the code of the other components so we can have a clearer vision of your problem, But you only want to track changes that happens on an object or an array in vue.js you need to deep watch them.
your watcher should be :

```
 watch: {
    recent_posts: {
       deep: true,
       handler: function( oldValue, newValue) {
          console.log( "recent_posts has changed" );
          // A post has been added, updated or even deleted
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in my original post. The prop in question that I am only concerned with is the :posts="recent_posts[0]" in the PostList component.

The PostFilter component works perfectly fine and as expected. I just need a way to get the PostList comp to refresh or a way for Vue to update.

Comment: yes, but how do i force the view/DOM to re-render to display the newly added post?

Comment: That's what reactivity is for, Vue.js does that for you, Since the watched object  ( recent_posts ) is binded to your template ( view ), then whenever and wherever its value changes it will update the view automatically